# XSL for-each layout problem

Tags: xslt

I have a fairly simple layout required.

```
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
  </li>Link</li>
</ul

<ul>
  <li>Link</link>
  <li>Link</link>
</ul>
```

However I get:

```
<ul>
  <li>Link</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  </li>Link</li>
</ul

<ul>
  <li>Link</link>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>Link</link>
</ul>
```

Im sorry I dont have the XSL to hand, network issues but thought id ask anyway with a brief explanation:

Essentially my xsl =

```
<for each select=x>

<ul>

<li>select=link</li>

</ul>

</for each>
```

Should I be doing:

```
<ul>

<for each select=x>

<li>select=link</li>

</for each>

</ul>
```

I also want to get a header for the list that is a result of grouping similar items,

```
<h3>select=header</h3>

<ul>

  <for each select=x>

    <li>select=link</li>

  </for each>

</ul>
```

Am i babbling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I be doing:

Yes, although you ideally also want an `if` around the whole thing so that in the event you don't have any items at all, you emit nothing, not even a `ul` with no items.

> Am i babbling...

Yes :)